# How to suppress Event Log entries for Security/File Access auditing

Tags: windows, security, windows-explorer, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have set up "Audit object access" on a Windows Server 2008-R2.  I then went to a specific folder properties/security/advanced/auditing and added an entry for Everyone and checked both Successful and Failed for the "Create files/Write data" item.

This all works fine and in Event-Viewer/Windows Logs/Security I'll see the Event ID 4656 with Task Category "File System" and I'll see my userid and "Notepad.exe" when I edit a file in that folder, as a test.   However, I also now see thousands (literally several thousand--as many as 50 per second) of other events of same Event ID but with Task Category of "Other Object Access" with details like "A handle to an object was requested", Object Server =  "PlugPlayManager", Process = Svchost.exe.   These didn't exist before setting up this auditing.

So, I know I can filter the event log by certain things, but not Task Category, and the main issue is that I simply don't care about those other events--I just want to track who edited a file, period.  I don't care about the thousands (and as I write this it's now in the tens of thousands) of those other events.  How can I stop those "Other Object Access Events" and *only* audit file edits?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was going to delete the question but I figure others may have the same question.  What I had to do was go down below in Local Security Policy's "Advanced Audit Policy Configuration" node and do two things:

1. Go to "Object Access" and choose Audit File System-->Properties-->Configure the following events-->(Check Success and Failure).
2. In Object Access, go to Audit Handle Manipulation-->Properties.  Here I do a little different--I chose "Configure the following events" and I did NOT check either, I just close the box. Then it changes the status from "Not Configured" (which apparently means "audit anyway") to "No Auditing".

I hope this helps someone.  I now see just my file-edit events.
(Note that this is in addition to the original action of setting the Audit Object Access and of course going to the folder itself, into Properties, Advanced, etc, and fiddling with the Audit tab's settings)